# How do I find out what library to use for an installed NuGet Package?

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm trying to include https://github.com/pomma89/Hippie with my project, but I'm not sure what library to include with 'using'.

How can I check for this instance and for future issues like this?

Comment: Pressing `Ctrl + . (dot)` on the line that requires the import provides you with a list of imports of namespaces that class exists in.. you would usually know from documentation which one to use.

Comment: @Adriani6 Wow, ok, I think that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to an example as seen on, https://github.com/pomma89/Hippie/blob/master/Examples/RawMessage.cs you can see that he is using `using DIBRIS.Hippie;` for example.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I never figured to check for examples. That really helps.

Comment: @EdwardSuzuki Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most

Comment: @JoãoFernandes There's isn't a close mechanism for questions :) And your answer doesn't really provide the answer for this question - in fact it should be a comment if there wasn't an examples page (which future readers might not have) your question wouldn't exist and I think we should be accounting for that.

Comment: @Adriani6 Checking for examples in a GitHub project it's a valid way to know what 'usings' you should be using. So in my opinion my answer shouldn't be a comment.

Comment: Totally, I get you - it's not a dig or negative comment :) What I mean is what if someone comes to read your answer and there aren't examples available? I think it would be worthwhile including the import lookup functionality built-in into Visual Studio (or relevant IDE).

Comment: @Adriani6 I'm here to learn :) . I understand your side of view. But (it is just my opinion) i never use a library that doesn't have examples or documentation that doesn't tell me how to implement.